# Prove that $\nu(n) \le \nu(2^{n}-1)$ where $\nu(n)$ is the number of positive divisors of n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, divisor-counting-function

Prove that $\nu(n) \le \nu(2^{n}-1)$

Ok so I have very few ideas for this question. I thought if I could find the prime decomposition of $2^{n}-1$, I could go somewhere with the formula for $\nu$, but I've had little success. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503502/prove-that-tau2n-1-geq-taun-for-all-positive-integers-n. Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24d(n)%20%5Cle%20d(2%5En-1)%24%2C%20divisor&p=1#)

Answer (score 0):

Prove that if $d$ divides $n$, then $2^d-1$ divides $2^n-1$.